# Is it possible to mark all messages as read instead of having to click on each one?

Tags: support, notifications, global-inbox

Is it possible to mark all messages as read instead of having to click on each one?

I have messages piled up that I have already read in the comments / answers / questions and don't want the red circle alerting me to read them again.

That is the red circle with a number in it that is over the inbox looking icon.

Comment: I mean, yeah, there's a text-link button with the words "mark all as read"

Comment: aaaaaaand they're gone. This is how unwanted the feature is, people realize they have to click twice to mark all messages as read and just have their account deleted.

Answer (score 4):

Here you go:

[image: ASMR markin all as read]